# Side-by-side identical axes3d with different orientation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the deformation of a 3D truss using `matplotlib`. Now, what I'm trying to do is show two views (side-by-side) of the exact same `axes3D` on the same figure, in this case one in isometric view and a side view. Can I do this with a minimal amount of copy-pasting?

I'm not including code as any example from the matplotlib webpage would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create a copy of the axes and just change its view angle. I think the simplest way would be to create a function, to which you pass the position of the subplot and the viewing angle.

Here's an example, based on the `lines3d_demo` example from the [mpl website](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.html)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,4))

def makeplot(position,angle):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(position,projection='3d')
    ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
    ax.view_init(30, angle)
    ax.legend()
    return ax

theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)

ax1 = makeplot(121,30)
ax2 = makeplot(122,60)

plt.show()
```

[image]